# How Many SharedPreference Files

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-xml, android-preferences

Just a quick question, and probably a stupid one so apologies.

Is it possible to have several SharedPreference files, for example:

```
getSharedPreferences('cakes', MODE_PRIVATE);
getSharedPreferences('tarts', MODE_PRIVATE);
getSharedPreferences('pies', MODE_PRIVATE);
getSharedPreferences('meringues', MODE_PRIVATE);
```

... and so on...

Is there a limit; or can the above even be achieved?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What's the point?  You're not going to be managing these by yourself anyway, so why do you care how many actual files (or in what format for that matter) Android creates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can multiple shared preference files. You could, for instance, use a different file for every user if you support user sessions.

Answer (score 1):

You can have many of those. The limit is very high - it basically creates a new file for every one. But there is no reason for doing that.